# VBA RTD failure in object oriented programming

Tags: excel

When I create recursion through in an infinite loop with a 1 sec OnTime delay. Excel seems to crash everything stops working. The only way to get it to start up again is through restarting the entire application. I was troubleshooting this through every possible angle. Eventually, the only thing that worked was not dimming any new objects in VBA & its been working fine for the past 8 hours... in the past when I wrote more complex code & utilized recursion through multiple object creations, for processing several hundred thousand rows of data, I'd see MULTIPLE instances of excel being created in my program manager bog down my computer's performance.

It seems object-oriented programming really reduced performance in VBA for large batch file processes but it's way easier & faster to write code...  & in many cases OOP is necessary.

I don't notice this OOP performance drop & crashing in other programming languages...

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this just VBA? Thanks!

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code.**

Comment: Definitely is not about VBA. Language can handle heavy operations with OOP. Some times I've noticed the way you instantiate objects-classes can leave them in memory and then when Excel is closed, you end up with "ghost" instances. But as Gary's Student said, Your code is crucial to anyone help you out here. In the meantime, check [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/lazy-object-weak-reference/)